# How to replace string with regex using awk editor?

Tags: regex, replace, awk, sed

shell command using sed editor

```
echo http://www.domain.com/?params | sed -e 's;https\?://;;' | sed -e 's;/.*$;;'
```

output
**www.domain.com**

How can i use the unix awk editor to output this string?

awk {print} ?

Comment: Do you REALLY need awk, as opposed to cut or some other tool? If you post a FEW lines of representative input, including any you think will be hard to parse, and expected output you might get a better answer than if you don't.

Answer (score 5):

You could try this,

```
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | awk -F/ '{print $3}'
www.domain.com
```

Through grep,

```
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | grep -oP '(?<=/)[^/]+(?=/)'
www.domain.com
```

Through sed,

```
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | sed 's/.*\/\([^\/]\+\)\/.*/\1/'
www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the perl/sed/awk/grep, this is actually pretty well-suited for cut:

```
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | cut -d/ -f3
www.domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

With awk and gsub:

```
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | awk '{gsub("\\/\\?params$", ""); print}'
http://www.domain.com
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | awk '{gsub("\\/\\?params$",""); gsub("^http://",""); print}'
www.domain.com
```

Or, (thanks Avinash Raj):

```
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | awk '{gsub(/\/\?params$|^http:\/\//,""); print }' 
www.domain.com
```

Perl:

```
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | perl -pe 's/^http:\/\/([^\/]+).*/\1/' 
www.domain.com
```

Or:

```
$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /^http:\/\/([^\/]+)/; ' 
www.domain.com
```

Comment: single gsub will do this job `$ echo http://www.domain.com/?params | awk '{gsub(/\/\?params|http:\/\//,"")}1'`

Answer (score 0):

Mix it up a bit

```
expr match http://www.domain.com/?params '.*/\(.*\)/'
```

or

```
expr http://www.domain.com/?params : '.*/\(.*\)/'
```

Incase there are more slashes later on

```
expr http://www.domain.com/?params/ : '.*//\([^/]*\)/'
```

Incase something really wierd is going on with the slashes

```
expr http://www.domain.com/?params/ : '[^/]*//\([^/]*\)/'
```